# SQL Query Get last visited date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have got two tables

**Customer**

[image]

**Pet**

[image]

What could be the possible sql query (Msaccess) for the following:

Output should be similar like this :
[image]

Comment: dbms oracle or access?

Comment: ms access or any sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the `JOIN` & use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT()` & `MAX()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.Cus_FName, ' ' c.Cus_LName), COUNT(p.Pet_ID), MAX(p.Pet_LastVisit)
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     Pet p
     ON p.Cus_num  = c.Cus_num 
GROUP BY CONCAT(c.Cus_FName, ' ' c.Cus_LName);
```

However, in MS Access the concat would be :

```
GROUP BY c.Cus_FName & " " & c.Cus_LName
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm!!! The join should have been p.Cus_num=c.Cus_num

Answer (score 0):

use join and aggregation

```
    select c.cus_num,c.cus_Lname,count(p.pet_id) as numberofpets,
   max(p.Pet_LastVisit) as last_visit
     customer c join pet p
    on c.cus_num=p.cus_num
     group by c.cus,c.cus_Lname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT(CONCAT(cus_fname, ' '), cus_lname) as customer_name, 
    count(p.pet_id) as number_of_pets,
    max(p.pet_lastvisit) as last_visit
from customer c, pet p
where c.cus_num=p.cus_num
group by customer_name
order by customer_name desc
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.